# Understanding NTFS-3g Inode Use

Tags: centos, ntfs, inode, nagios

I'm running a CentOS 4.6 final box with a second drive array (raid 1, the mount is `/mnt/raid`, as listed below in my nagios warning) that uses ntfs-3g as the file system. My nagios warnings just went off saying that I'm running out of inodes but still have 10% of the drive space available (I am aware this is common).

However I'm possibly mis-understanding the problem since when I do a `df -hi`, my output seems to indicate I only have a pending drive space issue. Also, NTFS does not use inodes, so what gives?

Here's my `df -hi` output

```
[root@images ~]# df -hi
Filesystem            Inodes   IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00
                        9.1M    190K    8.9M    3% /
/dev/hda1                26K      39     26K    1% /boot
none                    127K       1    127K    1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1                52M    141K     52M    1% /mnt/raid
```

here's my `df -h` output:

```
[root@images ~]# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00
                       72G  6.2G   62G  10% /
/dev/hda1              99M   15M   80M  16% /boot
none                  506M     0  506M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             466G  415G   52G  90% /mnt/raid
```

here's my `fstab` file:

```
/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00 /                       ext3    defaults        1 1
LABEL=/boot             /boot                   ext3    defaults        1 2
none                    /dev/pts                devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0 0
none                    /dev/shm                tmpfs   defaults        0 0
none                    /proc                   proc    defaults        0 0
none                    /sys                    sysfs   defaults        0 0
/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol01 swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
/dev/sda1               /mnt/raid               ntfs-3g  defaults        0 0
#/dev/md0                /mnt/raid/backup        ntfs-3g  defaults        0 0
/dev/sdd1               /extraid                ntfs-3g rw,umask=0000,defaults 0 0
/dev/hdc                /media/cdrom2           auto    pamconsole,exec,noauto,managed 0 0
```

And here's my Nagios warning:

```
DISK WARNING - free space: /mnt/raid 52452 MB (10% inode=99%):
```

The warning says free space, but 52GB is plenty at 10% available. What concerns me is the `inode=99%` part. Doesn't this mean Nagios is reporting that 99% of inodes on `/mnt/raid` are being used? `/mnt/raid` is NTFS, so I don't think it even uses inodes? Correct?

Comment: The NTFS driver for Linux (and possibly other Unices) uses inodes. As a reference, check fs/ntfs/inode.c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is complaining that there is only 10% free space left, which is not good.  It is saying 99% of the inodes are free.

Comment: Ah, ok thank you. I mis-read the `inode=99%` part as saying 99% of them were used. This appears to be a simple drive space issue, which is an easy fix. Thank you.